# VSCode debug console command line height

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to increase the line height of the debug console input line?
[image]

Comment: What? It's the height of a line of text. Why do you need that line of text to be increased? The debug console command is not a multi-line code input device; it's for debugging commands.

Comment: The is a GitHub Issue for this among other things: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1957. It started back in 2016 so I'm not sure when it's going to be in if ever.

Comment: It's so small! Hard to hit in a hurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/51725 ( Allow the user to resize the debug console input )

You can make the debug console input larger by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> with focus in the Debug Console **while in an active debug session**.  Just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it smaller again.

The `Debug Console Font Size` setting will increase/decrease the font size in the Console Input now - it didn't until recently (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/91261).